# Configurar o DatePicker do ng-bootstrap para PT-Br

Tags: bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-datepicker

Estou usando um DatePicker do **Ng-Bootstrap** com Angular 2 e quero colocar o formato da data (AAAA/MM/DD) para o formato (DD/MM/AAAA)

Também preciso alterar os dias e meses do calendário para Português.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bom consegui criando dois arquivos:CustomDatepickerI18n

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDatepickerI18n } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

const I18N_VALUES = {
    'pt-br': {
        weekdays: ['dom', 'seg', 'ter', 'qua', 'qui', 'sex', 'sab'],
        months: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
    },
};

@Injectable()
export class I18n {
    language = 'pt-br';
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomDatepickerI18n extends NgbDatepickerI18n {
    constructor(private _i18n: I18n) {
        super();
    }

    getWeekdayShortName(weekday: number): string {
        return I18N_VALUES[this._i18n.language].weekdays[weekday - 1];
    }

    getMonthShortName(month: number): string {
        return I18N_VALUES[this._i18n.language].months[month - 1];
    }

    getMonthFullName(month: number): string {
        return this.getMonthShortName(month);
    }
}
```

O segundo arquivo: NgbDatePTParserFormatter

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

function padNumber(value: number) {
    if (isNumber(value)) {
        return `0${value}`.slice(-2);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

function isNumber(value: any): boolean {
    return !isNaN(toInteger(value));
}

function toInteger(value: any): number {
    return parseInt(`${value}`, 10);
}

@Injectable()
export class NgbDatePTParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
    parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
        if (value) {
            const dateParts = value.trim().split('/');
            if (dateParts.length === 1 && isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
                return {year: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: null, day: null};
            } else if (dateParts.length === 2 && isNumber(dateParts[0])
                && isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
                return {year: toInteger(dateParts[1]), month: toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: null};
            } else if (dateParts.length === 3 && isNumber(dateParts[0])
                && isNumber(dateParts[1]) && isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
                return {year: toInteger(dateParts[2]), month: toInteger(dateParts[1]), day: toInteger(dateParts[0])};
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
        let stringDate: string = '';
        if (date) {
            stringDate += isNumber(date.day) ? padNumber(date.day) + '/' : '';
            stringDate += isNumber(date.month) ? padNumber(date.month) + '/' : '';
            stringDate += date.year;
        }
        return stringDate;
    }
}
```

Depois só informar eles como um provider no seu modulo:

```
    import { NgbDatepickerConfig, NgbDateParserFormatter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import { NgbDatePTParserFormatter } from './_services/NgbDatePTParserFormatter';
    import { NgbDatepickerI18n } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import { CustomDatepickerI18n, I18n } from '../_services/CustomDatepickerI18n';

        @NgModule({    
        providers: [
                PacienteService,
                [I18n, { provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: CustomDatepickerI18n }],
                [{provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDatePTParserFormatter}],
            ],
        })
```

[image: Happy coding!!]

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado por compartilhar essa tua solução, até agora e a mais completa que achei.
Sugiro apenas uma penquena correção no aray dos dias da semana, parece que faltou sexta e repetiu o domingo, segue como deixei:
```weekdays: ['dom', 'seg', 'ter', 'qua', 'qui', 'sex', 'sab'],```

Answer (score 6):

Na versão 8.3.15 do Angular CLI, importei no app.module.ts:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';

registerLocaleData(localePt);
```

E inseri o código abaixo dentro do providers do mesmo arquivo:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt'}],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

Comment: funcionou muito bem!

Answer (score 1):

A nova versão exige implementar o método abaixo, segue ajuste para deixar funcional.

```
getDayAriaLabel(date: import('@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap').NgbDateStruct): string {
 return date.day.toString();
}
```

Comment: Pode especificar qual é a "nova versão"? Daqui um tempo pode sair outra versão e a versão que citou pode não ser a mais atual.

Comment: Utilizei na versão 5.x.x; mas precisamente a versão 5.1.2